# Why cannot download some images on iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios

I have a issue that develop hybrid app using WKWebView in iOS.
Sometimes, it can't download some images like below capture image.
But when it reconnect these page after back, download images complete.

I don't understand it and can't fix bugs.

at first connect (sometimes)
[image]

after second connect
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the HTTP status of the failed images?

Comment: I have uploaded additional image. HTTP status is 200OK.